# Could you please assist me with an issue I'm encountering with Bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

When I add a Bootstrap class to a container, the CSS isn't loading. I installed Bootstrap through the terminal using "npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap" and imported it using "import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';".

Here is the code:
`return (

```
<div className='container-fluid'>
  <div className='row'>
    <MovieList  movies = {movie}/>
  </div>
</div>
```

)`

I checked the props. All works fine but somehow my css is not loading.

I also try to install like this npm i bootstrap@5.3.3 (latest version)

If anyone have any idea feel free to help. Thank you.

Comment: Remove double quotes before import and from the end.

Comment: how i miss that :/ thank you! <3